# why does c++ compiler no choose the constructor?

Tags: c++

```
class Yun
{
    int q;
    friend Yun operator+(const Yun& a, const Yun& b)
    {
        Yun c = a;
        c.q += b.q;
        return c;
    }
public:
    Yun(int i) :q(i) {
    }
    explicit operator int()
    {
        return q;
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    Yun y(3);
    int w = y + 2;
    return 0;
}
```

i make add the explicit to the operator int(),it will not be perform,why does compiler no choose the other way--performing Yun(int) to transform the second object--2.

And if i remove w value.

```
int main()
{
    Yun y(3);
    y+2;
    return 0;
}
```

it can work,why?

Comment: Because you've not defined any `Yun operator+(Yun const&, Yun const&)`.

Comment: i have edited,but it still can't work.

Comment: @paolo...........

Comment: Now the compiler will complain because you have marked the conversion from `Yun` to `int` as `explicit`. If you want the result as an `int`, do a `static_cast`. Otherwise, declare `w` as `Yun`.

Comment: You add `explicit` to tell the compiler to do conversions not implicitly, but only if you explicitly ask for it. The reason to use that is to add a conversion possibility but to prevent you from accidentally using that conversion in code.

Comment: The additional question in your edit has already been answered. `int w = ...;` does not consider `explicit` conversion operators to convert `...` to `int`. In `y+2;` there is no assignment that needs conversion. The error is not complaining about the `+` operation, it is complaining about the `int w = ` initialization.

Answer (score 3):

The user defined conversion

```
explicit operator int()
```

is marked `explicit` but

```
int w = y + 2;
```

requires an *implicit* conversion.

Just make the conversion explicit:

```
int w{y + 2};
```

Unrelated: Since the conversion doesn't change the `Yun` object, make it `const`-qualified:

```
explicit operator int() const
```

Comment: I prefer it the other way. I would make all functions explicit and explicitlly call them: `int w = static_cast<int>(y + Yun(2));`

Comment: @jabaa Yes, that's often recommended but not the case here. If one makes the constructor `explicit` and want the objects to be easily usable in these situations without casts, adding operators `Yun& operator+(const Yun&, int)` and `Yun& operator+(int, const Yun&)` would be preferable.

Comment: I have not thought about that at all. You're right. That's even better.

Comment: @jabaa It doesn't exclude your suggestion though. One often combines them.